# Using Quartz library , how to read cron expression from Database Table, instead of getting from properties file

Tags: java, spring, cron, quartz

```
@Scheduled(cron= "${time.export.cron}")
public void performJob() throws Exception {
   // do something
}
```

> This is from a properties file, it's working fine.
>   but I want to read corn expression via a database table instead of getting from the 
>   properties file. How we can aware system on which time job should run.

Comment: Are you using spring scheduler? This is not quartz

Comment: yes, this one is spring scheduler, but now I moved to quartz

Answer (score 0):

sure.
Add `org.quartz.jobStore.class` and db info through below properties.

```
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = false
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDS
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 20000
```

Official documentation for your information. http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/2.4.0-SNAPSHOT/configuration.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply , I will try to do this way

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to be able to modify the cron expression without having to redeploy your service.
Firstly cron triggers are created once. So you can have something like following in your app startup.

```
@PostConstruct
public void setupCronJobs() throws SchedulerException, ParseException {

}
private JobDetail cronJobDetail() {

        return JobBuilder.newJob()
                         .ofType(CLASS)
                         .storeDurably()
                         .withIdentity(YOUR_JOB_ID, YOUR_JOB_GROUP)
                         .build();
    }

    private Trigger cronJobTrigger(final JobDetail jobDetail) {

        return TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                             .forJob(jobDetail)
                             .withIdentity(YOUR_TRIGGER_ID, YOUR_TRIGGER_GROUP)
                             .withSchedule(cronSchedule("YOUR EXPRESSION HERE"))
                             .build();
    }
```

This will create a trigger config in table YOURSUFFIX_cron_triggers.
[image]

Either you modify it manually, or you can add an API call or something to update it.